# Laravel relationship (company addresses one-to-many many-to-one)

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have theese models setup.
`Company` and `CompanyAddress`

A `Company` can have many addresses so I have this in the `Company` model.

```
public function addresses()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\CompanyAddress', 'company_id', 'id');
}
```

A `CompanyAddress` should belong to a `Company` so I have this in the `CompanyAddress` model.

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company', 'company_id', 'id');
}
```

I've struggled with relationships before, but I get an error when trying to attach a address to a given company.

```
$company->addresses()->attach($address);
```

I also tried ussing `..associate()`

The error:
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::attach()`

What am I doing wrong here? Did I mess up the relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really should be `$company->addresses()->associate($address);`

There are a couple of ways to do this below:

```
$company = Company::where(['name'=>'eastman'])->firstOrFail();
$address = new CompanyAddress;
$address->company()->associate($company);
$address->save();
```

Or you could try something like this

```
$company = Company::where(['name'=>'eastman'])->firstOrFail();
$address = new CompanyAddress;
$company->addresses()->save($address);
```

Comment: The `save()` method worked. Thank you! Weird that `associate()` didn't though.
But thanks!

Comment: No problem yeah that is very weird.